# Has my CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS been set

Tags: cuda, cmake

I'd like cmake to tell me if my `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` contains "-arch sm_??".  That is, I'd like cmake to tell me if the CC info has been set.

How do I do this w/ cmake?
How can I get cmake to do a string search?  Do I need to use a regExp?

Somthing like this:

```
IF(${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} contains "-arch sm_")
  MESSAGE("-arch flag has been set"
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(" CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS: ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Please set the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS, CC level: -arch sm_??"
ENDIF()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`if(<variable|string> MATCHES regex)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aif) command; that does a regex match:

```
IF(${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} MATCHES "-arch sm_")
```